# Using a database in a Swift app to manage volunteers

Tags: ios, database, swift, sqlite, realm

To preface, I am very new to Swift.

I am in the planning process of building an app for my organization that manages our volunteers' information. I have read about using Realm or SQLite but my question is more concerning the upkeep of the database by those who manage the volunteers in my organization. Once the app is built and there is information in the database, how do people update it and keep up with it without having to log into the SQL DB. Is there a way to use any APIs to upload spreadsheets or CSVs to update the data?

Any help is welcome.

Comment: it is important to understand, that the SQLite is a Local database, means that all the data in this database will be users only and not a shared database between all users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a backend for your app to manage and update volunteer's information, syncing data directly between devices will be too complicated and just a bad design.

If you don't want to write your own server you should take a look on such services like `Parse.com` or `backendless`.

I personally use parse for my needs and it would be so easy to share and update any information you want without dealing with a server on your own. And unless your app is too popular, it is free.